# SelectMany creates lots of SQL select statements instead of one with join

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm writing a query with `SelectMany` and checked SQL it generates in LINQPad. The query is very simple.

Let's say I have 3 entities: `Customer`, `Order`, `OrderItem`. `OrderItem` holds info about what product is ordered and in what quantity.

I want to get all `OrderItems` for one customer.

```
context.Customers.First().Orders.SelectMany(o=>o.OrderItems)
```

I get result set as I expect, but SQL is really odd for me. There's a bunch of select statements. First it selects one customer, which is ok. Then it selects one Order (because this customer has only one), then is creates one select for each `OrderItem` in previously selected `Order`... So I get as many selects as there are `OrderItems` + `Orders` for selected `Customer`. So it looks like:

```
select top 1 from Customers;

select * from Orders where CustomerID = @cID;

select * from OrderItems where OrderID = @o1;
select * from OrderItems where OrderID = @o2;
select * from OrderItems where OrderID = @o3;
select * from OrderItems where OrderID = @o4;
```

What I would expect is something like:

```
select oi.* 
from OrderItems oi
join Orders o on o.OrderID = oi.OrderId
join Customers c on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
where c.CustomerID = @someID
```

One select, nice and clean.

Does `SelectMany` really works like that or am I doing something wrong, or maybe something wrong is with my model? I can't find anywhere examples on how that kind of simple `SelectMany` should translate to SQL.

This doesn't matter for small numbers, but when a customer would have 100 orders with 200 order items each, then there would be 20 000 selects...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the following for your query (to query for the order items of a specific customer with `someId`):

```
context.Customers.Where(c => c.Id == someId)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems))
```

Or - to reproduce the behaviour of `First()` but with a single DB query:

```
context.Customers.Take(1)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems))
```

You original query loads the customer with `First` (query 1), then *lazy loading* loads the `Orders` collection of that customer (query 2), then *lazy loading again* loads the order items collection for each loaded `Order` (query 3 to n). To avoid all those multiple queries you must not use a "query execution method" like `First()` or `ToList()`, etc. inside of your query expression.