# is it bad practice to have many selectMany statements when using Linq EF?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query which works but it just seems wrong, can this be shortened? also is the following bad for performance?

```
var projectBylineIDs = _neptuneUow.Projects.FindWhere(p => p.ID == 81)
                               .SelectMany(p => p.Batches)
                               .SelectMany(i => i.Items)
                               .SelectMany(b => b.ByLines)
                               .Select(b => b.ID)
                               .ToList();
```

Comment: This might produce many SQL queries, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721623/selectmany-creates-lots-of-sql-select-statements-instead-of-one-with-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see a bad practice here, if yo need this , do it.

What about performance. Performance is *extremely context sensitive subject*.
Depends on context of your code executing against, it can be very harmful of executes pretty sweet.

The questions that might ask yourself: do you need really all that information, that after you nee to flatten in sequence ? Or just run some *StoredProcedure* on server, and get ready to show result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I only need the batch ID, eg the last select .Select(b => b.ID), is it possible to get that without all the other select statements?

Comment: @xerxes: don't see other way then 1) rearchitecting your class for easier accessibility to that property 2) if not, *in some way* (linq or not) you need traverse inner lists to get to that field. So chose more appropriate way, that fits *your* requirements (performace, memeory efficiency, time you can spend on this...)